# How can I circumvent naming collisions when using Jar gradle task?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have a couple of dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
    compile 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
}
```

I put them into a jar distribution:

```
gradle distZip
```

But a couple of dependencies have the same name and version, so there are duplicates in the resulting zip file:

```
-rw-r--r--  0 0      0       50121 Aug 23 09:48 gradleTest/lib/compiler-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  0 0      0        5124 Aug 23 09:48 gradleTest/lib/runtime-1.1.1.aar
-rw-r--r--  0 0      0        9635 Aug 23 09:48 gradleTest/lib/runtime-1.1.1.aar
-rw-r--r--  0 0      0       11567 Aug 23 09:48 gradleTest/lib/common-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  0 0      0       20618 Aug 23 09:48 gradleTest/lib/common-1.1.1.jar
```

I've tried to rename the files in the zip, but I can't figure out how.
I've written a task that copies all dependencies to a 'lib' directory, but only the last dependency gets copied to the directory:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "lib"
    project.configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.getResolvedArtifacts().each { artifact ->
        println "${artifact.moduleVersion.id.group}.${artifact.name}-${artifact.moduleVersion.id.version}.${artifact.extension}"
        from artifact.file
        rename "(.*)", "${artifact.moduleVersion.id.group}.${artifact.name}-${artifact.moduleVersion.id.version}.${artifact.extension}"
    }
}
```

I have also looked at jar.eachFile to rename the files, but I can't figure out how to get the artifact group from inside that closure. My gradle skills are not complete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up copying the dependencies to a custom build directory, renaming them as I copied them:

```
task copyToLib() {
    project.configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
        println "${artifact.moduleVersion.id.group}.${artifact.name}-${artifact.moduleVersion.id.version}.${artifact.extension}"
        copy {
            from artifact.file
            into "${project.buildDir}/lib"
            rename "(.*)", "${artifact.moduleVersion.id.group}.${artifact.name}-${artifact.moduleVersion.id.version}.${artifact.extension}"
        }
    }
}
```

Using a copy closure instead of the copy task was the breakthrough for me. I couldn't think of a way to copy the artifacts while having access to artifact data such as version and group.